# How to get Option values of dropdown list in Java array from Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, drop-down-menu

I am using selenium with java. I have a huge drop down list alike this and I want to select this Dropdown list and get all options values in Java array so that I could print that or compare with another array. Can anyone please help me

```
<select id="cityID" name="cityID" class="">

<option value="">- Select city for Alaska - </option>
<option value="129467">Adak</option>
<option value="202770">Akhiok</option>
<option value="44455">Akiachak</option>
<option value="35798">Eielson Afb</option>
<option value="232756">Eielson Air Force Base</option>
<option value="152259">Elim</option>
<option value="22639">Elmendorf Afb</option>
<option value="182039">Emmonak</option>
<option value="117516">Yakutat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebElement drop_down =driver.findElement(By.id("cityID"));
Select se = new Select(drop_down);
List<WebElement> options = se.getOptions();
```

Then you can iterate over this list and do .getText();